# How to process Matrix field in controller

Tags: craft3, matrix

I am trying to process a text field inside a Matrix field.

In the controller I have this to get posted params:

```
$element->setFieldValuesFromRequest($fieldsLocation);
```

If I want to process a custom text field, I can do it easily with

```
$result=$element->getFieldValue('textFieldHandle')
```

which `$result` is exactly the text field value.

but if I have this text field in Matrix field, if I do this:

```
$result=$element->getFieldValue('matrixFieldHandle')
craft::dd($result)
```

I get a `craft\elements\db\MatrixBlockQuery` object which I don't know how I can fetch text value from this object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to loop the Matrix field first, something like this:

```
foreach($entry->matrixHandle->all() as $block) {
   echo $block->fieldHandle;
}
```

Comment: thanks @gioppe  i should have used one() or all() because it returns craft\elements\db\MatrixBlockQuery and i had to get result first